# How to compare two columns from two different files?

Tags: command-line, awk

I have two files which content are:

File 1:

```
ATOM      1  N   LEU     1     -10.186 -21.276  -0.497  1.00  2.00      PROT
ATOM      2  HT1 LEU     1     -10.773 -22.005  -0.843  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      3  HT2 LEU     1      -9.316 -21.441  -0.958  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      4  HT3 LEU     1     -10.007 -21.389   0.478  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      5  CA  LEU     1     -10.642 -19.924  -0.729  1.00  3.00      PROT
ATOM      6  HA  LEU     1     -10.092 -19.286  -0.214  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      7  CB  LEU     1     -10.604 -19.551  -2.214  1.00  3.00      PROT
ATOM      8  HB1 LEU     1     -11.432 -19.802  -2.731  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      9  HB2 LEU     1      -9.764 -19.989  -2.566  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM     10  CG  LEU     1     -10.447 -17.969  -2.340  1.00  3.00      PROT
```

File 2:

```
ATOM      1  N   LEU     1     -10.186 -21.276  -0.497  1.00  2.00      PROT
ATOM      2  HT1 LEU     1     -10.773 -22.005  -0.843  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      3  HT2 LEU     1      -9.316 -21.441  -0.958  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      4  HT3 LEU     1     -10.007 -21.389   0.478  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      5  CA  LEU     1     -10.642 -19.924  -0.729  1.00  3.00      PROT
ATOM      6  HA  LEU     1     -10.092 -19.286  -0.214  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      7  CB  LEU     1     -10.604 -19.551  -2.214  1.00  3.00      PROT
ATOM      8  HB1 LEU     1     -11.432 -19.802  -2.731  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM      9  HB2 LEU     1      -9.764 -19.989  -2.566  1.00  4.00      PROT
ATOM     10  CG1 LEU     1     -10.447 -17.969  -2.340  1.00  3.00      PROT
```

I want to compare the third column in both files and if those are the same, at the same line, prints the value of column 2 at that specific matched values and "ok". Otherwise print the value of column 2 and "error".

My first tried was:

```
awk -F"\," 'FILENAME=="file1"{A[$3]=$3} FILENAME=="file2"{if(A[$3]){print "$2 ok"}}' file1 file2
```

But, it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is *"at the same line"* - that suggests you need to index the array with the record number in the current file, `FNR`, rather than with the field value `$3`

Ex.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$3; next} {print $2, $3 == a[FNR] ? "ok" : "error"}' file1 file2
```

Alternatively, if you know how many columns there are in the first file (let's call it *N*), you could just paste them side by side and then just compare `$3` with `$(N+3)`

Ex.

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '{print $2, $14 == $3 ? "OK" : "error"}'
```

*Note I omitted the `-F","` because your files as posted are whitespace delimited not comma delimited - if they are actually CSV files, add it back.*

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference-verbs.html#join) to combine two tables:

```
$ mlr -p join -j 2 --lp a --rp b -f file1 then \
  put -q 'print $2.(($a3 == $b3) ? " ok" : " error")' < file2
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, after a few years working with logs and source files is Comparing files using the User Interface in Visual Studio Code, for small files. It's easier to manipulate, create a report, etc.

[image: Visual Studio Code]