# awk - compare two files and print all columns from both files

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I want to compare two files

File 1:

```
evm.TU.PTPU-T1.     PF00808
evm.TU.PTP-T1       PF00498 
evm.TU.PTPX-T1      PF00250
evm.TU.PAN-T1       PF00817
```

File 2:

```
PF00808 CL0012  Histone CBFD_NFYB_HMF   Histone-like transcription factor 
PF00498 CL0357  SMAD-FHA    FHA FHA domain
PF00817 CL0123  HTH Forkhead    Forkhead domain
```

Output:

```
evm.TU.PTPU-T1 PF00808  CL0012  Histone CBFD_NFYB_HMF   Histone-like
evm.TU.PTP-T1 PF00498   CL0357  SMAD-FHA    FHA FHA domain
evm.TU.PAN-T1 PF00817   CL0123  HTH Forkhead    Forkhead domain
```

I tried the below command

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in a){print $0,a[$1]}' file2 file1 >file3
```

but it is printing only the second column of the file 2, not the entire line.

```
PF00808 evm.TU.PTPU-T1 CL0012
```

Please let me know how to add the entire matched line of file 2 to the output and not just the second column

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251013/how-to-compare-two-columns-from-two-different-files?rq=1

Comment: It looks like you want `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1; next} ($1 in a){print a[$1], $0}' File1 File2`

Comment: @steeldriver: it is not working

Comment: @Annotator I'm sorry - could you please elaborate a bit more? (is there a error? if yes: Post the log! If no: What is it that doesn't work?)  It's really difficult to know what "didn't work" for us - if no other info is posted :)

Comment: William Martens: it is not generating any output (no error)

Comment: temporary solution is just to switch the file names; awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} ($1 in a){print $0,a[$1]}' file1 file2  >file3

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options here:

1. save whole lines `$0` of `File2` into an array keyed on its `$1`; then look up `$1` of `File1` based on the key in its `$2`:

   ```
    $ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} ($2 in a){print $1,a[$2]}' File2 File1
    evm.TU.PTPU-T1. PF00808 CL0012  Histone CBFD_NFYB_HMF   Histone-like transcription factor
    evm.TU.PTP-T1 PF00498 CL0357  SMAD-FHA    FHA FHA domain
    evm.TU.PAN-T1 PF00817 CL0123  HTH Forkhead    Forkhead domain
   ```
2. save the `$1` values of `File1` keyed on its `$2` then look up the corresponding whole lines of `File2` based on the key in its `$1`

   ```
    $ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1} ($1 in a){print a[$1], $0}' File1 File2
    evm.TU.PTPU-T1. PF00808 CL0012  Histone CBFD_NFYB_HMF   Histone-like transcription factor
    evm.TU.PTP-T1 PF00498 CL0357  SMAD-FHA    FHA FHA domain
    evm.TU.PAN-T1 PF00817 CL0123  HTH Forkhead    Forkhead domain
   ```

Comment: both are not working...not generating any output.

Comment: @Annotator `awk --version`

Comment: @bac0n: GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0

Comment: @Annotator both will fail to produce output if you transpose the file order - please check you are using the appropriate order of `File1` and `File2` in each case. **Note that it is different between the two solutions.**

Comment: @steeldriver: sorry I tried but not working...

Comment: @Annotator OK then you will need to hope someone else posts an answer that works for you

Comment: @Annotator do `dos2unix yourfile1 yourfile2` then try again